# How To Stop Installation of Multiple Slice APK In Android Studio 2.3

Tags: java, android, apk

After updating the android studio to version 2.3. i am facing issue during installation on android device from android studio.
here attaching the output raised in console before and after updating the android studio.

**Before updated to android studio 2.3**

```
$ adb push E:\mynewapp\TestDemo\TestDemo\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.gangsofcoder.testdemo
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.gangsofcoder.testdemo"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.gangsofcoder.testdemo
Success
```

**After updated to android studio 2.3**

```
$ adb install-multiple -r E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk 
 E:\SurajBahadur\testdemoApp\testdemo\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
```

Error while Installing APKs

[image: This is prompt getting during installation]

Comment: press ok it will reinstall the app. its because your system signature changes.

Comment: i did this step so many times but it doesn't work . i  am getting this issue after updated to latest android studio ide 2.3.

Comment: try with disabling instant run.  File->settings->searchbox(type instant run)-> select disable option.

Comment: Did you notice $adb install -multiple . i don't know why this happens

Comment: Thank you Sohail Zahid, after disable instant run it works fine for me.

Comment: @SurajBahadur this bug has been reported.. hoping it will be fixed soon https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235995

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This is caused by "instant run" feature in studio 2.3, you can disable it by:

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.

More info, please check:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

Comment: I had a similar issue and had to disable Instant Run.  It was telling me it couldn't install my app in TEST_ONLY mode, but adding the `-t` argument to the install options of my run configuration wasn't actually adding it to the new install-multiple ADB command.  So currently there's a bug there.

Answer (score 14):

Here's my solution (there's no need to deactivate instant run)
Do all these steps in the stated order:

1. Gradle Build (root level)

   [image: Gradle Build]
2. Gradle build + clean (app level)

   [image: Gradle Build App Level]
3. Choose app on the top bar (left of run 'app')

   [image: Gradle Build App Level]
4. Clean Project

   Navigate to Build > Clean Project

And it should work now!

- Solution 2: disable instant run (as stated by Teresa)

Comment: However disabling isntant run is just a provisory solution.. if you really want to fix it follow the 4 steps as stqted

Comment: It may also help to press: Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 7):

I had same error in Redmi Note 3.

For Xiaomi devices,Go to Developer options and turn off MIUI optimization.
After device is rebooted it will work.

[image: Android Developer options MIUI optimization]

See: http://en.miui.com/thread-255506-1-1.html

Answer (score 5):

Just hit *Tab* Build> Clean Project in android studio. You are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Check if multiple activities have set to `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Instant run worked for me just go to settings and search for instant run just disable apply changes rerun the app it will install correctly.

[image: step 1 choose settings from file menu]

[image: look for instant run just disable that and apply changes]

it should work

Answer (score 1):

After looking at Ginggas answer I found this solution that worked for me:

1. Clicking on `Build` and then `Clean Project.`
   [image: Build->Clean Project]
2. Clicking on `Build` and then on `Rebuild Project`
   [image: Build->Rebuild Project]

After that it worked like a charm again :)

Answer (score 1):

For me just Build -> Clean Project worked. I had to uninstall the app on the test device.

Here is the option to clean project. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using mac and could not find Instant Run option in that. I tried doing `invalidate cache and restart` and it worked.

Comment: Go to AndroidStudio->Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment. You can find the Instant Run option there.

Answer (score 0):

For those using mac, do Build apk(s) from build menu.
And install apk through
adb install -r /app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the slice-apk issue and it worked after Invalidate Cache / Restart command under Android Studio File menu. Disabling Instant Run is not required.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE SOLUTION:

getting rid of the instant run is a terrible "solution". To get things working again for me, I upgraded my grade to 5.4.

Just go to

```
File >> project structure >> Gradle version
```

You should be able to edit it to be the most up to date version. 
Hope this helps.