# Migrating Projects from Mac OS to Windows

Tags: android, windows, macos

I was using Mac OS for developing my android projects. And now Im moving to Windows System,so I wanted to migrate all my earlier android studio projects into my windows system environment.
Anybody please help me to how to move all the android projects to windows at once...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be using Git or some other source control system for all your projects. If you use a service such as GitHub or BitBucket, migration will be trivial (literally just clone the repository on your Windows machine).

Answer (score 0):

Android projects (if you use Android Studio) are Gradle project, so there is no need to do any config at all, you just have to copy them from mac OS and import them into Android Studio using Windows and they will work just fine. Even if you open them using Android Studio it will propose you to fix the local properties but I would suggest to import them instead.

Comment: Yes I did like wise... So when I import an application gradle sync was perfect. and when I try to run it in emulator I will get an error saying "Installation failed with message Invalid File: C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\ContextMenu\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices_7.apk. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the app if it is present, and then re-installing."  Im not getting what to re-install and where?

Comment: That's is not related to the project but to android studio itself, follow this to resolve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/42776487/6171845