# Android studio - not able to install apk

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am trying to install apk from android studio. Initially I got below error:

[image]

So I disable instant run as suggested in many post on stackoverflow like this [How To Stop Installation of Multiple Slice APK In Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672157/how-to-stop-installation-of-multiple-slice-apk-in-android-studio-2-3/43425612).

Now I am getting below error after disabling instant run:

> java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine Error while Installing APK

I have only one instance of android studio running when I got this error.
Android studio version is 3.3.1. What can be cause of above error.

Also I am not able to install apk using `adb install` command. I am getting message failed to install apk with no detail message.

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding project it often works

Comment: I did that many times. Did not work.

Comment: Have you tried invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: yes I have tried invalidate cache and restart. Did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out why I was not able to install apk from studio or from adb install command. Issue was due to my pc usb port was blocked by network administrator of our organization as my usb port usage period expired. So if anyone facing issue of not able to install apk and getting error as mentioned in question and no solution working for you than please check if your pc ports are not blocked by your organization network admin. I took approval to use usb port and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart Android Studio : **File** -> **Invalidate caches/restart**

And i think you install **ADB-Idea** pluggin to uninstall or clear app data very easy with shortcut.

ADB-Idea pluggin :

[image: ADB-Idea pluggin]

[Link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7380-adb-idea)

Answer (score -1):

You have got the first error because of :

- You are testing your project_A on a emulator_E
- As you had the app project_A, installed on the emulator_E, in previous run.
- Now you started the execution of your project_A, again on the emulator_E.
- The Android_Studio and emulator_E, both came to know that, the apk is already on the emulator_E, so just, whatever the new changes are, will be synchronised, within the, already available project_A apk, on the emulator_E.
- But as the whole process takes some time, you uninstalled the apk of project_A on a emulator_E.
- And now project_A on a emulator_E is not there, but Android_Studio tried to synchronised it, which leads you to the `ERROR_1`

**Solution**

You are following many approaches, for the same thing.

You are starting your project, project_A on the emulator_E by :-

1. via `ADB INSTALL` from the command line too
2. With Instant Run too
3. With Instant Run too
4. And you are not keeping the previous apk as it is there on the emulator_E, after starting the execution too.

Uninstall it from emulator_E, but before you start the execution for emulator_E. Which lead to your Android Studio to some dangerous STATE_A and, Android Studio is not tested by google for such types users

It may seem harsh, and obviously it is not the answer, but this is the exact problem, which is leading you to the such case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not testing on emulator but on real device and also I tried on multiple devices on which app was never installed and app is not installed in device when I am trying to install and got error.

Comment: @anujprashar, If such is the case then, you have not configured the developer settingS of the device, as it is required, there was a time, it was quick & easy, now its a bit complex & needs to set multiple settings, again 99% devices are not android, they are modified custom ROMS have settings much hidden & shocking